# Black bar/footer at the bottom of chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate and Google Chrome. There seems to be an annoying black bar or footer appearing every once and now. Why is this happening. When it appears, i close the tab and reopen the same in new tab, then the bar disappears.

Has anybody encountered this behavior or know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like its a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81487).

It has been fixed in the next release. You can download the Chrome 13 beta release from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Browsers/Google-Chrome.shtml).

Besides refreshing the page, the problem is also said to go away if you press `Ctrl + Shift + B` (toggle bookmarks bar).

Comment: Such an odd issue.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to remove the "black footer" I found is to maximize/restore the window. In Windows 7 this means you can just grab the top of the window if it's maximized, pull it off the top of the screen to demaximize it, let go, and them push it against the top of the screen to remaximize it.